# Sequelize Hooks - does the funcs expose the Models as in the associations?

Tags: triggers, hook, sequelize.js

When creating a `hook` I want to know if the `models` variable is exposed in the function like in the assosiations:

```
...
classMethods: {
    associate: function ( models ) {
        users.belongsTo( models.roles, { foreignKey: 'role' } );
    }
}
...
```

What I'd like to do is to update the a value of another model, first I have to update the current amount of product adding the amount purchased (any tips?), so, I need the `models` var.

```
hooks : {
    afterCreate: function ( inventory, options ) {
        //What does the `options` value has?
    }
}
```

One workaround suggested was to simply require the model...
Also I would like to know if `afterCreate` would work for `bulkCreate`? Or does it necessary has to be `afterBulkCreate`?

Answer (score 0):

afterCreate is triggered after each creation. afterBulkCreate is triggered after the whole set has been created. So if you are creating 10 items, afterCreate would be called 10 times, after each item was created. But afterBulkCreate would only be called once.

This doesn't seem to be documented throughly enough but I'd suggest just creating a hook and then doing console.log(arguments) inside the hook to see which arguments are beeing passed in. But I'd suggest to just require the model like you said.

Answer (score 0):

The `models` variable is not exposed in the function. The solution I found when I need to update the value of another model is the following:

Define a function to get the hooks that receives the models:

```
var getHooks = function(models) {
    return {
        afterCreate: function(item, options) {
            // Can access the models:
            models.roles.create({...});
        },
        beforeCreate: function(item, options) {
            // Code here
        }
    };
};
```

And set the hooks functions in the `associate` method:

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function ( models ) {
        users.belongsTo( models.roles, { foreignKey: 'role' } );

        var hooks = getHooks(models);
        for(var name in hooks) {
            users.addHook(name, hooks[name]);
        }
    }
}
```